# What is the difference between IDE and SATA controlers?

Tags: virtualbox, vboxmanage

On my Kali Linux storage devices,I have SATA and IDE controllers. What is the difference between them?
I added kali and created kali.vdi disk on SATA?
I sthis the right choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual explains the differences between IDE and SATA quite well and recommends SATA

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html

> Serial ATA (SATA) is a newer standard introduced in 2003. Compared to IDE, it supports both much higher speeds and more devices per controller.
>   ...
>   Like a real SATA controller, Oracle VM **VirtualBox's virtual SATA controller operates faster and also consumes fewer CPU resources than the virtual IDE controller**
>   ...

Answer (score 2):

IDE is an older, slower protocol, in fact I'm not sure anyone make IDE drives these days, the SATA spec - which is quite old now too - is much faster and more capable, and you can buy the drives too.